# How to change Tomboy's spell checking language

Tags: 14.04, tomboy

I am using Tomboy 1.15.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. For some strange reason Tomboy is (randomly?) underlining perfectly correct English words. I would like to check or switch the language, but according to [bug 116290](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/116290) this is not possible directly in Tomboy.

In the bug thread there is a reference to [a fix for Intrepid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/116290/comments/7), that allows the user to switch the language in a programme called `gtkspell`. I have a package with that name installed, but it seems to be a simple code library.

How can I change the language in `gtkspell`? Or is there another way of switching the language dictionary used by Tomboy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the language in the context menu by clicking the RMB. Unfortunately, after Tomboy restarting language changes again to the original. And I join to the question - how to change the default language?

A similar discussion:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336484#c16

> This bug isn't exactly fixed, but in gtkspell 2.0.15 there is a new
>   Languages submenu in the right-click menu that allows you to change
>   the language being used for spell-checking.
>
> We just need to be able to save that setting.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Although not being a conventional answer, this post actually contains a solution. I do not mind much that changes are not stored, I write in different languages.

Comment: Is the *Language* option in the context menu something new? I never noticed it before.